# Working with pipes, getting error my pipe isn't declared

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm making a program that will basically mimic

```
    find $1 -name '*'.[ch] | xargs grep -c $2 | sort -t : +1.0 -2.0 --numeric --reverse | head --lines=$3
```

The program is to fork into 4 child processes and the output of the first is the input to the next. Right now it's saying that my pipe12 and pipe23 aren't declared. They clearly are but I'm not sure if they may be in the wrong spot or something else is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry for all the weird commented out blocks.

```
    [cs@cycle2 ipc]$ make clean
    rm -f finder pipe tmp1 tmp2
    [cs@cycle2 ipc]$ make build
    gcc -Wall -g finder.c -o finder
    finder.c: In function ‘main’:
    finder.c:45:15: error: ‘pipe12’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if ((dup2(pipe12[1], 1)) < 0){
           ^
    finder.c:45:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    finder.c:95:15: error: ‘pipe23’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if ((dup2(pipe23[1], 1)) < 0){
           ^
    finder.c:73:11: warning: unused variable ‘count’ [-Wunused-variable]
       ssize_t count;
       ^
    make: *** [build] Error 1
    [cs@cycle2 ipc]$ vim finder.c


    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <strings.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    #define BSIZE 256

    #define BASH_EXEC  "/bin/bash"
    #define FIND_EXEC  "/bin/find"
    #define XARGS_EXEC "/usr/bin/xargs"
    #define GREP_EXEC  "/bin/grep"
    #define SORT_EXEC  "/bin/sort"
    #define HEAD_EXEC  "/usr/bin/head"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
      int status;
      pid_t pid_1, pid_2, pid_3, pid_4;



    //  int pipe(int pipe12[2]),pipe(int pipe23[2]),pipe(int pipe34[2]);
        int pipe(int pipe12[2]);
        int pipe(int pipe23[2]);


      if (argc != 4) {
        printf("usage: finder DIR STR NUM_FILES\n");
        exit(0);
      }



      pid_1 = fork();
      if (pid_1 == 0) {
        /* First Child */


      char cmdbuf[BSIZE];
      bzero(cmdbuf, BSIZE);
      sprintf(cmdbuf, "%s %s -name \'*\'.[ch]",FIND_EXEC, argv[1]);

        if ((dup2(pipe12[1], 1)) < 0){
            perror("pipe12 broke in process 1");
            exit(-1);
        }
        close(pipe12[1]);
        close(pipe12[0]);
            if ( (execl(BASH_EXEC, BASH_EXEC, "-c", cmdbuf, (char *) 0)) < 0) {
     fprintf(stderr, "\nError execing find. ERROR#%d\n", errno);
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }


        /*
        if((execl("/usr/bin/find","find","-name","*.[ch]", (char *)NULL)) < 0){
    perror("execl 1 didn't work. child 1");
    exit(-1);
       }
    */
        exit(0);
      }



    //----------------------------------------------------------------------


      char buffer;
      ssize_t count;

      pid_2 = fork();
      if (pid_2 == 0) {
        /* Second Child */

        if ( (read(pipe12[0], &buffer, 1))< 0){
            perror("read broke in pipe12 process 2");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if ((dup2(pipe12[0],0)) < 0){
            perror("");
            exit(-1);
        }
        close(pipe12[1]);
        close(pipe12[0]);


      char cmdbuf[BSIZE];
      bzero(cmdbuf, BSIZE);
      sprintf(cmdbuf, "%s %s -c %s ",XARGS_EXEC, GREP_EXEC, argv[1]);

        if ((dup2(pipe23[1], 1)) < 0){
            perror("pipe23 broke in process 2");
            exit(-1);
        }
        close(pipe23[1]);
        close(pipe23[0]);


        if((execl(BASH_EXEC, BASH_EXEC, "-c", cmdbuf, (char *) 0)) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError execing find. ERROR#%d\n", errno);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }

    /*
        if((execl("/usr/bin/xargs","grep","-c",argv[1], (char *)NULL))< 0){
            perror("execl 2 didn't work. child 2");
            exit(-1);
        }

    */
        exit(0);
      }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------


      pid_3 = fork();
      if (pid_3 == 0) {
        /* Third Child */
        exit(0);
      }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------


      pid_4 = fork();
      if (pid_4 == 0) {
        /* Fourth Child */
        exit(0);
      }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------


      if ((waitpid(pid_1, &status, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process 1 encountered an error. ERROR%d", errno);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      if ((waitpid(pid_2, &status, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process 2 encountered an error. ERROR%d", errno);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      if ((waitpid(pid_3, &status, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process 3 encountered an error. ERROR%d", errno);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      if ((waitpid(pid_4, &status, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process 4 encountered an error. ERROR%d", errno);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }

      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This bit here:

```
int pipe(int pipe12[2]);
int pipe(int pipe23[2]);
```

declares twice a function `pipe` accepting an array of two integers.<sup>1</sup> Instead I assume you want to declare two arrays of two `int`s and call `pipe` with them as arguments. If you replace the above with

```
// declare two arrays of two ints each called pipe12 and pipe23
int pipe12[2];
int pipe23[2];

// call pipe with them.
pipe(pipe12);
pipe(pipe23);
```

It compiles, and this part of the program will work. I have not checked the rest of the program.

<sup>1</sup>Actually a function `pipe` that accepts a pointer to `int` for reasons that are not terribly important for this. If you're interested: Arrays cannot be function arguments, but pointers to their elements can, and because of this there's a special rule in the standard that says that array declarators in the argument list of a function have the meaning of a pointer to the elements of the declared array type. Long story short: `int pipe(int foo[2]);` is equivalent to `int pipe(int *foo);`.

Comment: That's interesting because in slides from class they use 
    int pipe(int foo[2]);

Comment: There's no problem with doing it (in fact I'd argue that it's a good thing to do), but it's only a declaration of intent. You see the function signature, and you immediately know you're supposed to put an `int[2]` into it, but it is not enforced. The compiler will accept `int i; pipe(&i);` (although your program will behave strangely, so don't do that).